# RangeQuery with Integer fields not giving expected result

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-entitymanager

following are two fields defined in the entity

```
@Column(name = "min_price")
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@NumericField
@FieldBridge(impl = IntegerBridge.class)
private Integer minPrice;

@Column(name = "max_price")
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@NumericField
@FieldBridge(impl = IntegerBridge.class)
private Integer maxPrice;
```

full text query is generated using entityManager as following

```
BooleanJunction priceBooleanJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
    //Building range query for price
    if (minPrice != null) {
        Query rangeQueryMinPrice = queryBuilder.range().onField("minPrice").above(minPrice).createQuery();
        priceBooleanJunction.must(rangeQueryMinPrice);
    }
    if (maxPrice != null) {
        Query rangeQueryMaxPrice = queryBuilder.range().onField("maxPrice").below(maxPrice).createQuery();
        priceBooleanJunction.must(rangeQueryMaxPrice);
    }

    BooleanJunction combainedBoolean = queryBuilder.bool();

    if (!priceBooleanJunction.isEmpty()) {
        combainedBoolean.must(priceBooleanJunction.createQuery());
    }

    Query searchQuery = combainedBoolean.createQuery();
    FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(searchQuery, ServiceProvider.class);

    LOGGER.info(query.toString());
```

the last log prints the following for 40, 90 input

```
FullTextQueryImpl(+minPrice:[40 TO *] +maxPrice:[* TO 90])
```

database contains the values (min,max) as (50, 80) and (80, 90)

still result is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The `IntegerBridge` you are using is using string encoding, but you want to make sure to use numeric encoding when using a range query. There is no need to add `@FieldBridge` in your case.

Also the behavior will depend on which version of Search you are using. Pre version 5 you needed to add `@NumericField`, but as of Hibernate Search 5, numbers will be automatically indexed numerically, in which case `@FieldBridge` as well as `@NumericField` is not required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are minPrice and maxPrice needed in your entity ? Your article has a minPrice and a maxPrice ? If you do it for full text search, you don't need it.

try to use `IntegerNumericFieldBridge` instead of `IntegerBridge` like this :

```
@Field @FieldBridge(impl=IntegerNumericFieldBridge.class)
private Integer price;
```

After that use `NumericRangeQuery` instead of hibernate search range query. Like this :

```
NumericRangeQuery<Integer> integerQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("price", minRangePrice, maxRangePrice,  true, true);
```

If you have many queries, you will not be able to use hibernate search bool() method, use lucene "BooleanQuery" instead. Like this :

```
BooleanQuery luceneBooleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
luceneBooleanQuery.add(integerQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST); // MUST or SHOULD
luceneBooleanQuery.add(anotherQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

You can mix lucene queries like `NumericRangeQuery` and queries built by the QueryBuilder of hibernate search.

Then, you can do this :

```
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneBooleanQuery, YourClass.class);
```

It should work.